# How to use mysql sandbox to build s - m - m -s topology?

Tags: mysql, replication

I want to build this topology

```
 M1  <->   M2    
 |         |
 S1        S2
```

I've checked `sandbox --help` and it seems that it can only build:

- `M  ->  S`

  ```
  make_replication_sandbox mysql-5.6.tar.gz
  ```
- `M  <->  M`

  ```
  make_replication_sandbox  --master_master mysql-5.6.tar.gz
  ```
- `M  <->  M  <->  M  <->  M  <->` (circular)

  ```
  make_replication_sandbox --circular=4 mysql-5.6.tar.gz
  ```

But how can I build

```
 M1  <->   M2    
 |         |
 S1        S2
```

Answer (score 1):

Well afaik you can't if you rely on mysqlsandbox to orchestrate it for you. But you can create a master-master for M1 <-> M2 and then create two standalone instance and configure each one to slave off of one master. It's pretty easy since you have all replication user created "rsandbox".